# Java pattern to create objects

Tags: java

My recent exposure was mostly to non OOP languages, so wonder any pattern or practice to do the below.

I need to write a function, which takes a json string (json array of objects) and produces list of objects (say `Student`). I checked the [creational patterns](http://today.java.net/article/2009/10/28/applying-creational-design-patterns-java), but doesn't seems to fit. Do you think I should write a helper class just to create these objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a kind of `util` class already, this kind of function would fit nicely in that class.  I wouldn't make a completely separate class just for this.  For instance, something like:

```
public static List<Student> parseJsonToStudents(String jsonData) ...
```

You could, however, have a constructor in your `Student` class which accepts a json String as a parameter and constructs the `Student` object from that.  *That* would definitely be taking advantage of OO principles.  But the [GSON package](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) renders a lot of that kind of thing obsolete and you might not want to bother programming it yourself.  It has in it `fromJson()` and `toJson()` methods which will parse the data and construct the objects for you.

Comment: interesting, I was using it in Android, and read somewhere I could use GSON. Will explore further. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could write a method that takes a JSON string and a class object and returns list containing objects of the given type:

```
public static <T> List<T> parseJsonList(String json, Class<T> theClass) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Student> studentList = parseJsonList(studentJsonText, Student.class);
List<Teacher> teacherList = parseJsonList(teacherJsonText, Teacher.class);
```

---

As @Jeff mentions, it would probably be better to create constructors for *Student* and *Teacher* that accept a JSON string.

Or you could have a static method in the Student class that creates a List of Students from a JSON string.

Or you could create an ObjectFactory class that creates objects of different kinds.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Action {

  public static class Response {

    private int _resultCode;
    private int _count = 0;

    public Response() {}

    public int getResultCode() { return _resultCode; }
    public int getCount() { return _count; }

    public void setResultCode(int rc) { _resultCode = rc; }
    public void setCount(int c) { _count = c; }
  }

  private List<Response> responses = new ArrayList<Response>();
  private String _name;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, some explanation regarding your answer would be a good idea.